# How can I use PHP to access one file with many MYSQL credentials

Tags: php, mysql, database, web, passwords

For example: I have two applications (App1 and App2) but both have different logins. Each app starts off as the following or similar

```
include ("/config/yourcreds.php");
$mysqlconnect = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $database)
                    or die ("Sorry, There was an issue connecting to database");
```

and the configuration file should have something like this:

```
CREDS1: $host="localhost", $pass="pass1", $user="user1", $database="database1"
CREDS2: $host="localhost", $pass="pass2", $user="user2", $database="database2"
```

I realize I am just making it complicated by not using:

```
$host="localhost" 

$user1="user1" 
$pass1="pass1"
$database1="database1"

$user1="user2" 
$pass1="pass2"
$database1="database2"
```

but I like the idea of selecting the credentials for uniform development across all my apps...can something like this be done with PHP?

Comment: Any reason you couldn't create a `.ini` file and read it in with [the INI reader routines](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php)? You can split those up into sections if you want.

Comment: @tadman I am researching that possibility right now. Thanks

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to do it with an ini file but figured it out with XML...would this be a good substitute? as I am using the follwoing example:
$xml=simplexml_load_file("creds.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");
$username1 =  $xml->credentials[0]->host
$username2 =  $xml->credentials[1]->host

Comment: XML files are usually a lot more ugly than `.ini` or `.json` but whatever works for you. That could work.